# like button doesn't works

Tags: facebook-like, confirm

On some of my pages, the like button doesn't work. I have two behaviors :

- The click on the like button display the message "add a comment" with the like button, just on the bottom on the button, but this message close after 1 seconds and nothing happend.
- Or It displays a confirm button. When I click on this, I have a popup where I can confirm the like.
  When I click on the like button on this popup, the popup closes and the like isn't counted, I always have 0 liker.

Here is my page :
www.samhigan.com/testf.cfm (I updated this link since the publication of this message)

I had just put the facebook code on this page to check that it doesn't come from another tag.

Have you got an idea ? I have searched on the facebook bug list but I can't find any solution.

Thanks,
Best regards,
Matthieu

Comment: The HTML markup at your page is wrong (i.e. there is an extra closing div tag).

Comment: Yes, I delete the last one. But there is always the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Did you test the like button by click and cancel it frequently? It will cause Facebook think your page maybe a spam and add a confirm button. There is no way to remove it manually, it will auto-disappear after a number of confirm have been click.

Here is an official response about this problem :
Facebook Developers > Bugs > [Like button requires Confirm step](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/412902132095994/)